# Pass env value to docker-compose command through bash script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, docker

I am using the following `docker-compose.yml` file (excerpts)

```
version: '3'
services:
 app:
    build: .
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    ports:
    - "36081:36081"
    restart: always
    container_name: my-application
    environment:
    - MIGRATE=$MIGRATE
```

The `MIGRATE` variable is assigned when I run `MIGRATE=N docker-compose up`. Everything works as expected.
However, when I run the same command in a bash script `my-script.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MIGRATE=N docker-compose up
```

the docker-compose command does not recognise the `MIGRATE` variable and defaults it to a blank string.

Also tried,

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MIGRATE=N 
docker-compose up
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export MIGRATE=N 
docker-compose up
```

with no luck. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try sourcing the script. `source ./my-script.sh`

Comment: @Jetchisel I'm just trying to run the script as `bash my-script.sh`. Where should I source the script?

Comment: In the command line interactive terminal.